# Why I cannot Navigate the html file by using WebView inside of the App in Wpf?

Tags: wpf, windows-community-toolkit

I make a Wpf projcect which demos how to use WebView to Navigate a html file inside of the App, but fails.

The main cs file code is below:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.wv.ScriptNotify += Wv_ScriptNotify;

        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private async void Wv_ScriptNotify(object sender, Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.WebViewControlScriptNotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        //await (new MessageDialog(e.Value)).ShowAsync();
        textBlock.Text = e.Value;

        //返回结果给html页面
        await this.wv.InvokeScriptAsync("recieve", new[] { "hehe, 我是个结果" });
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //我们事先写好了一个本地html页面用来做测试
        this.wv.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web://Assets/index.html");
        //this.wv.Source = new Uri("http://www.baidu.com");
    }
```

And the html file index.html is inside of the project, located at `Assets/index.html`. Its source code is here:
https://github.com/tomxue/WebViewIssueInWpf/raw/master/WpfApp3/Assets/index.html

I put the project code onto GitHub: https://github.com/tomxue/WebViewIssueInWpf.git

If the project works well, when WebView visits the inner html file, it should show a button at first.
But I saw nothing.

**More:**

According to the accepted answer(Thank to Pavel Anikhouski), I changed my code as below and it now works.

```
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //我们事先写好了一个本地html页面用来做测试
        //this.wv.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web://Assets/index.html");
        //this.wv.Source = new Uri("http://www.baidu.com");

        var html = File.ReadAllText("../../Assets\\index.html");
        wv.NavigateToString(html);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/rel/3.0.0-preview/docs/controls/WebView-known-issues.md) with `WebView` control in `WindowsCommunityToolkit`

> - You can use only absolute URIs to resources in members of the `WebView` control that accept string paths.
> - `WebView` controls don't recognize the `ms-appx:///` prefix, so they can't read from the package (if you've created a package for your
>     application).
> - `WebView` controls don't recognize the `File://` prefix. If you want to read a file into a `WebView` control, add code to your application that
>     reads the content of the file. Then, serialize that content into a
>     string, and call the `NavigateToString(String)` method of the `WebView`
>     control.

So, instead of loading a file `this.wv.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web://Assets/index.html");` try to read a local file and then navigate to the string

```cs
var html = File.ReadAllText("Assets\\index.html");
this.wv.NavigateToString(html);
```

It should work fine (I've seen the button and message at my end). Also, don't forget to copy `Assets\index.html` to the output directory (set *Copy Always* or *Copy if newer*)